# Getting error in VsCode C# (Omnisharp) when select the second project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I use the vscode 1.48.0, c# extension 1.23.0. I use workspace and have more than one project inside workspace. The problem is when i select second project omnisharp give an error " Error: command 'o.fixAll.solution' already exists". I have to restart the vscode. But still get so many warning from omnisharp until i remove all project from workspace and put just one project in workspace.

So, if i have to use c# extension, i always remove all project from workspace and put only one that i want to work. It is so tiring. Projects are webapp. Does anybody has this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The appears to be an [open issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2952) for this with the Omnisharp project